# How can i send data which comes async from back end from child to parent component

Tags: angular

I have two components.Parent ( match compo ) and child ( filter compo ).I want to pass data from child to parent component.If i have static property then when i do something like this it works.3 gets printed.
But if i have some subcribe method where i am getting data in the child and i try to access on this was in the parent compo then i get undefined on the matches property.

```
//filter compo ts file

  test = 3;
    this.matchService.getMatches().subscribe(matches => {
      this.matches = matches['pageOfItems'];
    })

//match compo html

<app-filter #varName></app-filter>

// match compo ts file
@ViewChild('varName') someElement;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.someElement.test);
    console.log(this.someElement.matches);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the Output property in the official documention the "Parent listens for child event" section.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1):

One way to send data from a child component to a parent component is by using an [Output](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) and an [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).

A basic example could look like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    template: '<button (click)="onValueChanged(3)">Click me</button>'
})
class ChildComponent {
    @Output() public valueChanged = new EventEmitter<number>();

    onValueChanged(value: number) {
        this.valueChanged.emit(value);
    }
}

@Component({
    template: '<child-component (valueChanged)="onValueChanged($event)"></child-component>'
})
class ParentComponent {
    onValueChanged(value: number) {
        console.log('value from child =', value);
    }
}
```

Note how the parent 'subscribes' to the value changes in the template. You can pass any value at any time you want from the child component this way.

Comment: @Matyhn Thanks for your reply.Can i send data on this way without an event,so for example when i subcribe and get some data in ngOnInit method in the child component ?

Comment: Another way to send data between components is to use a service. However since this is a child component which wants to communicate with a parent component I think using an EventEmitter is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Since `matchService.getMatches()` is an `async` operation, you will not be able to use the data before it reaches the Filter component.

The right way to do it is using the `@Output()` decorator (see the [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties)) which helps you send an event with a payload from the Child component to the Parent component.

You can then `emit()` the data from the Child component inside the `.subscribe()` function call or whenever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

`this.matchService.getMatches()` of your **child component** (filter component) is async request. You will never exactly assure of that this async task will be completed before your **parent component**'s `ngAfterViewInit()` invoked. So send your child component updated value to parent component using [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter). Try to add EventEmitter at your child component and emit the data to parent component.